# tee: /proc/acpi/ibm/fan: Invalid argument

Tags: 16.04, bash

As root, I run

```
root@myself:~# echo disable | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan; sleep 5; echo enable | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

but I get

```
disable
tee: /proc/acpi/ibm/fan: Invalid argument
enable
tee: /proc/acpi/ibm/fan: Invalid argument
```

How is it possible, when I run as root?

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you have the thinkpad-acpi driver loaded and your hardware is supported?

Comment: What does `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` output? Did you take any preparatory steps such as those listed here [thinkwiki: How to control fan speed](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed)

Comment: @SebastianStark It could be useful to mention how to verify this. I am sure that this file is continuously updated. But how is it related to the `tee` question?

Comment: your command is fine, but the driver does not seem to understand "disable" or "enable" or writing to that file at all. This usually happens if the hardware is not supported or something like that. Also, the /proc interface for the thinkpad-acpi driver is deprecated, see @steeldrivers link.

Comment: Also check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/114010/thinkpad-fan-control-via-procfs

Comment: @SebastianStark the `tee` command tries to write to a file as a root. Why would it fail? I think the driver expects something like "status:  enabled", because that's the first line there. The file is regularly updated with the current fan speed, does it not mean that thinkpad-acpi driver can control the fan speed?

Comment: @rapt it needs the `fan_control` option to be enabled in the kernel module: if it is, you should see a line like `commands: enable, disable` when you `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` - if you don't see that,then your command will fail

Comment: @steeldriver 1. I never mentioned any driver in my question. I simply asked why I cannot edit a file with `tee` as a root. Whether this editing would have any effect other than updating the file is a different question. 2. The link you provided seems to be outdated for my OS, this one looks better http://andrewjackson.name/blog/2016/08/07/set-up-thinkfan-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t430-ubuntu-16-04/ 3. What does update this file then?

Comment: (1) it's not really a file (except in the sense that "everything in Linux is a file") - see for example [What happens when I run the command cat /proc/cpuinfo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121703/65304) (2) it appears to work on my T400s running 17.10 (3) we've covered that already I think - there is nothing wrong with your `tee` command (although the `sudo` is superfluous when you are already `root`) **if** you have enabled `fan_control` in the `thinkpad_acpi` kernel module

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not with your `tee` command - although since you are already in a root shell you could have used a simple redirection `echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` (and could certainly have removed the `sudo`).

Although "everything in Linux is a file", the reality is that "files" in `/proc` are really interfaces to the running kernel and **don't** behave exactly like regular files - if we use `strace` we can see that the error doesn't really come from `tee`, but from the underlying `write` call to the open file descriptor (I changed the syntax from a pipe to a here-string to make sure that we are tracing the `tee` not the `echo`):

```
root@t400s:~# strace tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan <<< 'disabled'
execve("/usr/bin/tee", ["tee", "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
.
.
.                              = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
read(0, "disabled\n", 8192)             = 9
write(1, "disabled\n", 9disabled
)               = 9
write(3, "disabled\n", 9)               = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "tee: ", 5tee: )                    = 5
write(2, "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan", 18/proc/acpi/ibm/fan)      = 18
.
.
.
+++ exited with 1 +++
root@t400s:~#
```

The reason the argument is invalid is that by default, the `thinkpad_acpi` module does not enable fan control - if you `cat` the file, you will likely see just a few lines as follows:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     enabled
speed:      1838
level:      auto
```

In order to enable fan control, you need to pass an option to the module during loading, which you can do using a configuration file:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf 
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

which you can either create in a text editor, or using

```
echo 'options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf
```

(this **is** just a regular file, so no issues with `tee` this time). Then you will need to reboot - unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to remove and re-load the `thinkpad_acpi` module on the fly.

After rebooting to re-load the module with its new option, you should see that it now lists some additional `fan_control` commands:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     enabled
speed:      3737
level:      auto
commands:   level <level> (<level> is 0-7, auto, disengaged, full-speed)
commands:   enable, disable
commands:   watchdog <timeout> (<timeout> is 0 (off), 1-120 (seconds))
```

**Now** you should be able to enable/disable/modify the fan parameters, either by writing to `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` directly with a command such as your `tee`, or using the `thinkfan` utility described in your link.

For further background about `/proc`, see [What happens when I run the command cat /proc/cpuinfo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121703/65304)

Comment: Yes, it's possible to reload `thinkpad_acpi` on the fly with `sudo modprobe -r thinkpad_acpi && sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi`. No need to reboot anymore!